# How to search a list of strings and remove all extra characters based on a list of names?

Tags: r, regex

I have a data frame with a list of titles and other info, as well as a corresponding list of names.  What I would like to do is extract the names from the titles and add them in a new column ("Players) at the end.  I've exhausted my admittedly small R knowledge, and can not find a way to get this to work with the corresponding list of names.

```
names <- c("Mookie Betts", "Cody Bellinger", "Mike Trout", "Ronald Acuna")

titles <- c("asdfasdf Mike Trout asdfasd", "jashfjasf Mookie Betts hasjdfhasj", "asdfuiojhuo Ronald Acuna ashdfj", "uiwqtruhjhb Cody Bellinger asdfasdf", "asdhfjaf Ronald Acuna ahsdfj", "hajsdf Mookie Betts ahsdfj")
```

I cannot figure out how to extract only the names.  Whenever I think I have it solved, it returns the whole title string.

Comment: `stringr::str_extract(titles, paste0(names, collapse = "|"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a regex expression from your `names` like so:

```
patterns <- paste0(names, collapse = "|")
```

and use the `stringr` package to extract these names from `titles` (ignoring case as requested in a comment):

```
library(stringr)

str_match(titles, regex(patterns, ignore_case = TRUE))
#      [,1]            
# [1,] "Mike Trout"    
# [2,] "Mookie Betts"  
# [3,] "Ronald Acuna"  
# [4,] "Cody Bellinger"
# [5,] "Ronald Acuna"  
# [6,] "Mookie Betts"
```

Comment: This works great.  I really appreciate it.  One problem came up when running through some data sets though:  How do I make the regex search not be case sensitive?  Sometimes the names that are hidden within the titles are in all caps, and those currently return a NA.

Comment: See my updated answer to add case insensitive regex.

Comment: Literally was just coming back to post that I had figured out the exact same thing that you had posted.  That works exactly how I want it to.  Thanks a whole lot!

Answer (score 1):

These one-liners use no packages or regular expressions other than fixed strings.

**1)** We grep the names in the titles and then reorder to the original order:

```
with(stack(sapply(names, grep, titles, fixed = TRUE)), ind[order(values)])
## [1] Mike Trout     Mookie Betts   Ronald Acuna   Cody Bellinger Ronald Acuna  
## [6] Mookie Betts  
## Levels: Mookie Betts Cody Bellinger Mike Trout Ronald Acuna
```

**2)** This creates a matrix whose rows correspond to names and whose columns correspond to titles.  The position of the single TRUE in each column is the index of the name corresponding to that title.

```
names[colSums(outer(names, titles, Vectorize(grepl)) * seq_along(names))]
## [1] "Mike Trout"     "Mookie Betts"   "Ronald Acuna"   "Cody Bellinger"
## [5] "Ronald Acuna"   "Mookie Betts"
```

**3)** In the example in the question there are always 4 words in each title and the middle 2 words are the name.  If that were always the case then we could extract the names without even using the `names` vector:

```
with(read.table(text = titles, as.is = TRUE)[2:3], paste(V2, V3))
## [1] "Mike Trout"     "Mookie Betts"   "Ronald Acuna"   "Cody Bellinger"
## [5] "Ronald Acuna"   "Mookie Betts"
```

Comment: I'm interested for some other problems: is there a performance gain with these solutions compared to using `stringr`, say when `length(titles) > 1e5`?

Comment: Don't know. Use the microbench or rbenchmark packages to find out.